# How to find the text() when I click on particular element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

when I click on "press me" span text , I need to get "fold2" `text()` value. I tried to add lot of jquery traverse methods in my script, but I can't find the perfect one.

Because of  my `<li>` including lot of `<span>` tag available.

**HTMl Code:**

```
<li class="favdelParentFold">
    <a href="#parentLevel1" data-toggle="collapse" class="" aria-expanded="true">
       <span class="caret-right"></span>
    </a>
    <span class="folder"></span>
    <span style="color:red;">fold2</span>
    <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFavorites_ModalDel" class="trashcan">press me</span>

    <ul class="collapse in" id="parentLevel1" aria-expanded="true">
    </ul>

</li>
```

**JS Code**

```
// when click on "press me" text I need to get span value of fold2

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".favdelParentFold span").click(function(){
var tr=$(this).closet().find('a').text();
alert(tr);//Expecting output is "fold2"
});
});
```

Working Code

https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/383/

Comment: closest() is for getting parent element. use prev() (according to your html)

Comment: use $(this).prev().text();

Comment: you have a typo. Put `.closest()` instead of `.closet()`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/atg5m6ym/389/ - `var tr = $(this).prev('span').text();`

Comment: Also fold2 is not in a n "a"

Comment: How do users access your "press me" control if they don't have a mouse or other pointing device (and aren't using a touch screen)? Seems odd that you have inaccessible controls like that, yet you have also defined `aria-` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Via jQuery, simplest way would be (if for some reason there's really no way to put class on your target):

```
$('.trashcan').on('click', function(e) {

  var prev = $(this).prev();

  if (prev.length)
  {
      alert( prev.text() );
  }

});
```

In this case, the code only works if the target is just before the source element.

Another is, assuming your target has a class of `.target`:

```
$('.trashcan').on('click', function(e) {

  var parent = $(this).closest('.favdelParentFold');

  if (parent.length)
  {
      alert( parent.find('.target').text() );
  }

});
```

Better to have the class so you can move around your target and the code would still work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

If you want to get the "fold2" text, you can set `click` event for `span.trashcan` alone. On this `click` event you can get that value by using `prev("span")`.

```js
// when click on "press me" class i need to get span value of fold2

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".favdelParentFold > .trashcan").click(function() {
    var tr = $(this).prev('span').text();
    alert(tr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="favdelParentFold">
  <a href="#parentLevel1" data-toggle="collapse" class="" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="caret-right"></span>
  </a>
  <span class="folder"></span>
  <span style="color:red;">fold2</span>
  <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFavorites_ModalDel" class="trashcan">press me</span>

  <ul class="collapse in" id="parentLevel1" aria-expanded="true">
  </ul>

</li>
```

Hope you are expecting this...

Comment: :this script triggers nested list also (" parentLevel1")

Comment: Then use child selector `>` like this. `$(".favdelParentFold > .trashcan")`

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam Is that helped or still facing issue?

Comment: its another scenario .your previous command was working fine . if u have any idea pls share

Comment: **Another scenario** means? I couldn't get you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270004/how-to-select-all-list-items-but-list-items-dont-have-nested-child-of-ul-or-o

Answer (score 0):

Please use it like this: ( Tested )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".favdelParentFold span").click(function(){
    var tr = $(this).prev().text();
    alert(tr);//Expecting output is "fold2"
    });
});
```

Comment: This script is corrupted child <ul> how to stop it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have added a class for text - `press me` text as `pressMe`. Please find the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/svu7Lzgq/). The code is as below:

**HTML**

```
<li class="favdelParentFold">
        <a href="#parentLevel1" data-toggle="collapse" class="" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="caret-right"></span>
        </a>
        <span class="folder"></span>
        <span style="color:red;">fold2</span>
        <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFavorites_ModalDel" class="trashcan pressMe">press me</span>

        <ul class="collapse in" id="parentLevel1" aria-expanded="true"></ul>

    </li>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pressMe").click(function () {
        alert($(this).prev().text());//Expecting output is "fold2"
    });
});
```