# How to select all list items but list items don't have nested child of <ul> or <ol>

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to select all list items in child of "**.favdelParentFold**" but make sure list items not have any nested child of `<ul>`. If list items have any nested child "`<ul>`" I don't want to trigger it.

HTML

```
<li class="favdelParentFold">
    <a href=""><span class="caret-right"></span></a>
    <span class="folder"></span><span>fold2</span><span class="trashcan">press me</span>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="">One 1</a><span class="trashcan">press me</span></li>
        <li><a href="">Two 2</a><span class="trashcan">press me</span></li>
        <li><a href="">Three 3</a><span class="trashcan">press me</span></li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Four 4</a><span class="trashcan">press me</span>
            <ul>
                <li>four 1.1</li>
                <li>four 1.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".favdelParentFold ~ ul li.trashcan").click(function () {
        var tr = $(this).prev('span').text();
        var pa = $(this).closet().text();
        alert(tr);
        alert(pa);
    });
});
```

**EX:**

If I click on one 1, two 2, three 3 I can get the this value and parent value but four 4 have child of `<ul>` I want to avoid triggers.

**Expected o/p:**

If click "one 1" i need to get one 1 and fold2

If click "one 2" i need to get one 2 and fold2

If click "one 3" i need to get one 3 and fold2

But we don't trigger "four 4"

Comment: @Azim: When i click on fold2.1 i need to get values "fold2.1" and "fold2" and also when i click on "doc 6" i need to get "doc6" , "fold2.1" and "fold2" values. same as "fold2.2" also pls guide me

Comment: @Azim: if u have any idea guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like following.

```js
$(".favdelParentFold ul li .ecm-trashcan").click(function() {
    var tr = $(this).prev().text();
    var ma = $(this).closest('.favdelSubFold').find('#sfDel').text();
    var pa = $(this).closest('.favdelParentFold').find('#pfDel').text();
    alert(tr);
    if(tr!=ma) alert(ma);
    alert(pa);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="favdelParentFold">
    <a href=""><span class="caret-right"></span></a>
    <span class="folder"></span><span>fold2</span><span class="trashcan">press me</span>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="">One 1</a><span class="trashcan">press me</span></li>
        <li><a href="">Two 2</a><span class="trashcan">press me</span></li>
        <li><a href="">Three 3</a><span class="trashcan">press me</span></li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Four 4</a><span class="trashcan">press me</span>
            <ul>
                <li>four 1.1</li>
                <li>four 1.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**Update:** according to fiddle html the `js` will be like this:

```
$(".favdelParentFold ul li .ecm-trashcan").click(function () {
    if ($(this).parent().find('ul').length || $(this).closest('.favdelSubFold').length) return;

    var tr = $(this).prev('a').text();
    var pa = $(this).closest('.favdelParentFold').find('#pfDel').text();
    alert(tr);
    alert(pa);
});
```

Comment: i am integrating your code https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/400/ but not working buddy . Advise me.

Comment: Your given `html` and fiddle `html` are different. Anyway I've updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/402/ @GobinathMahalingam

Comment: :Thanks . In fiddle updated code "fold2.1" and "fold2.2" have nested list i dont dont want to triger it and also child of "fold2.1(doc6)" and "fold2.2(doc7)" .

Comment: When i click on fold2.1 i need to get values "fold2.1" and "fold2" and also when i click on "doc 6" i need to get "doc6" , "fold2.1" and "fold2" values.


same as "fold2.2" also pls guide me .

Comment: When i click on fold2.1 i need to get values "fold2.1" and "fold2" and also when i click on "doc 6" i need to get "doc6" , "fold2.1" and "fold2" values. same as "fold2.2" also pls guide me .

Comment: I've updated my answer and the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/417/ @GobinathMahalingam

Comment: i updated my code https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/433/ pls verify my approach was correct

Comment: Seems ok. Sorry for my mistake. See this http://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/436/ @GobinathMahalingam

Comment: i this expecting o/p was correct but problem is when i click on "fold2.1" or "fold2.2" is having direct child of "<ul>" . in this case i need "fold2.1" for folder name  not for document name. Code http://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/461/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102986/discussion-between-gobinath-mahalingam-and-azim).

Comment: now we facing issue like that one 1, one 2, one 3 having no child so that this is come from as "Document Name".